# Structure 2d array segm fault C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, segmentation-fault

I want to create a matrix that contains 2 information in every cell so I decided to do a two-dimensional struct. Even more, I must allocate dynamically the memory for this task. 
When I run the following code the program ends up with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" .... I tried to debug this using printf() and I saw that everything works except the part of code after calling the createMap (R, map).

Here is my code :

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Maps {
    int height;
    int gloves;
};

void read (int *R, int *P) {
    scanf("%d%d", R, P);
}

void createMap (int *R, struct Maps **map) {

    free(map);
    map = calloc (2 * (*R) + 1, sizeof(struct Maps *));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * (*R) + 1; ++i) {
    map[i] = calloc (2 * (*R) + 1, sizeof(struct Maps));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * (*R) + 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * (*R) + 1; ++j)
        {
            map[i][j].height = i + j;
            map[i][j].gloves = i + j;
        }
    }

}

int main () {
    int *R = malloc (sizeof(int));
    int *P = malloc (sizeof(int));
    struct Maps **map = malloc (sizeof(struct Maps *));
    read (R, P);   // work

    createMap (R, map); // kind of executes but there are no data stored  
    printf("%d\n", map[0][0].height);

    free (R);
    free (P);
    return 0;
}

// code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/v77FbttE
```

Comment: You're passing `map` by _value_.  The function `createMap` immediately frees that memory, then allocates new memory.  The pointer to that memory is stored in a temporary copy of `map` that is only available while inside your function.

Comment: I'm not very goot at C, can you help me to correct the code, please ?

Comment: It's not even a full program.  I have no idea what the `read` function does.  It's very strange that you're allocating memory for a single integer, and I suspect it's because you don't understand how pointers and value referencing works.  If I was to correct your code, I would change nearly all of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. C uses value semantics on function calls. You're passing map but you're not receiving the pointer back, so in fact you're examining the old allocated map, and not the reallocated map.
2. You should use reference when calling functions:
   int R, P;
   struct Maps **map;

   read (**&R**, **&P**);

   createMap (**R**, **&map**);

and define the functions accordingly. In createMap - *map = ...